# Are there dynamic typings on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I have a specific use-case for typings which I find hard to implement.

I have the concept of "Service" classes on my python codebase, which are classes with a handful of functions I want to "expose" so only they will be available when using an API. The implementation of the Service is like this:

```
class MyService(BaseService):
    def normal_function(self):
        pass

    @exposed
    def exposed_function(self):
        pass
```

What's happening behind the `@exposed` thing is that it adds a unique property to the wrapped method which allows someone who uses it to know which functions are "exposed" or not.

I wish to make a type smart enough to understand that only the "exposed" functions are available.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**name mangling**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

```
class MyService():
    def __normal_function(self):
        pass

    def exposed_function(self):
        pass

my_service = MyService()
my_service.exposed_function() # this works, user can use the exposed function
my_service.__normal_function() # error: MyService instance has no attribute '__normal_function'
my_service._MyService__normal_function() # normal_function can only be called using its "mangled" name
```

In this case, the name of the normal function - `__normal_function` - will be textually replaced with `_MyService__normal_function`, so that the user will not be able to call the function using its "original" name.

Note that the normal function can still be called outside of the class, since private variables and methods don't exist in Python, but name mangling is probably the closest you can get to implementing private-like behavior.